# Как передать локальные переменные в TimerTask?

Tags: java, java-timertask, java-timer

Пусть при отправке сообщения некоторому списку подключений необходимо запустить таймер ожидания **подтверждения доставки**.

Для хранения множества ожидаемых подтверждений доставки заведена некоторая карта:

```
HashMap<Thread, ArrayList<MessagePacket>> aConfirmationMap = new [...];
```

Эта карта заполняется при отправке сообщений (каждый пакет перед отправкой добавляется в список ожидания своего `Thread`'а).

Для реализации таймера ожидания я решил использовать `TimerTask` добавленный в `Timer`:

```
for (SocketThread thread : aConnectionThread)
{
    aConfirmationMap.get(thread).add(packet);   

    // Добавление заданий проверки доставки
    aConfirmationTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {                       
        public void run()
        {
            // TODO: обработка истечения времени ожидания подтверждения доставки.

            // !!! Нет доступа к локальным переменным !!!
            if(aConfirmationMap.get(thread).contains(packet))
            {                                   
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

    thread.syncWrite(packet.bytes);
}
```

И результат вполне ожидаемый, **ссылка на локальные переменные недопустима**:

> Cannot refer to the non-final local variable packet defined in an
>   enclosing scope

**Вопрос**: как создать задания ожидания **подтверждения доставки**, ответственные за переотправку сообщений, каждое из которых хранило бы свою пару `Thread`-`MessagePacket` (для проверки, был ли удалён `MessagePacket` из массива ожидания, или нет)?

Comment: Что мешает добавить `final` к `packet` или добавить переменную `final localPacket = packet`, или вынести кусок кода в отдельный метод с параметром `final packet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом деле, для того, чтобы дать `TimerTask()` доступ к **локальной переменной функции** (и даже к **локальной переменной итерации**), достаточно дать им модификатор `final`:

```
protected void broadcasting(final MessagePacket packet)
{
    for (final SocketThread thread : aConnectionThread)
    {
        aConfirmationMap.get(thread).add(packet);   

        // Добавление заданий проверки доставки
        aConfirmationTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {                       
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO: обработка истечения времени ожидания подтверждения доставки.

                // !!! Есть доступ к локальным переменным !!!
                if(aConfirmationMap.get(thread).contains(packet))
                {                                   
                }
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);

        thread.syncWrite(packet.bytes);
    }
}
```